# jenkins does not read build.properties

Tags: maven, build

I am trying to build my maven project using jenkins . it create war file but not able to read build.properties file so all the css,images path not getting reflect.

Please share if you know.

Comment: build.properties is not a file normally used by Maven. I deeply suspect that you're running an ANT build from within Maven.... Not enough detail provided to analyse your issue. I've removed the tag for jenkins.... Doesn't seem related. Does this build work from the command line? I suspect not. That is where you should start your analysis

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, it will be difficult to understand what you want.
But I guess that you are used to build with Ant, which is filtering your resources.

So, if you want to do the same, you can use the maven-resources-plugin, which is triggered automatically when you run mvn:package (or beyond).

Here an example:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.xml</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.xml</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>

    <filters>
        <filter>build.properties</filter>
    </filters>
      ...
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

If I'm mistaken, please post you pom and your template configuration files.